# When can a service be destroyed and where inserting the stopSelf() method?

Tags: android

I'm reading [the official documentation about Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), but I'm a little bit confused because some things aren't so explicit.

Let's take this snippet:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID) {
        while(...any condition...) {
            //some actions
        }

        return START_SOMETHING;
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My doubts are the followings:

1. The Android system can destroy a service not bound to the current focused activity and not declared as in foreground. But can the Android system destroy a service even if it is still in the `while` loop?
2. When I call `stopService()` does it wait for the `onStartCommand()` to get to the return statement?
3. Where should I insert the `stopSelf()` call? Just before the return statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the Android system destroy a service even if it is still in the while loop?

Yes. For some reason, extreme low memory pressure (for example), Android system kills the `Service` without calling `onDestroy()` method. Why? Because of `Service` always runs on UI thread.

> When I call stopService() does it wait for the onStartCommand() to get to the return statement?

No. Return statement's action will be executed when Android system kills the `Service`. But, if you call `stopSelf()` manually, the return statement's action will be ignored.

> Where should I insert the stopSelf() call? Just before the return statement?

Call `stopSelf()` wherever and whenever you want. For example, if user press a button, call `stopSelf()` to stop the `Service` playing a music.

Comment: What happens if I start a service which performs a long action and it is killed by the system before it grasped the return statement?

Comment: @welcome, that will never happen. Once `onStartCommand()` is called, it will call the 'return statement' directly. To perform a long running action, you need to create a `ServiceHandler` which extends `Handler`.

Comment: What do you mean with " Once onStartCommand() is called, it will call the 'return statement' directly."? If I put a for cycle in this method won't it be executed?

Comment: @welcome, for example the `Service` returns `START_STICKY`, so the code in this cycle will be executed quickly until `return START_STICKY;`, but doesn't guarantee that `onDestroy()` method will be triggered by system once the `Service` gets killed. Additionally, asynchronous thread never gets executed in `onStartCommand()`. Hence, you need a `ServiceHandler`.

Comment: @welcome, putting `while` loop in `onStartCommand()` is not a good practice. You should put it in a `ServiceHandler`.